# Bevel not working corectly

Tags: modeling

Ik I already asked a lot of questions today, but im trying to make a 3d model from scratch and running into a lot of problems, I'm trying to do this:
[image]

This is from a youtube tutorial but this happens when i try to use the bevel tool on mine
[image]

anyone know why? Please help if you could. I can't seem to find this anywhere else

here is my blender file:  [image]

and here is the YouTube tutorial I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BANJc53Eik

Comment: The bevel tool doesn't like corners where three or more edges connect.

Comment: Try using the Inset Faces tool instead. It looks like that's what was used in the first image.

Comment: oh~ he said in the video that he used the bevel tool but it never worked for me. I'll try that though. Although I never heard of it so it will probably take longer than it should for me to solve the problem. Thanks for the quick response though

Comment: Ifg you post your blend file I can help more.

Comment: Ik this sounds stupid but how do I do that? I'm new to blender >.<

Comment: Don't feel stupid for asking questions. That's the only way to learn anything is to ask questions! :-) Go to www.pasteall.org and upload there, then post the link here.

Comment: oh! thanks for the help. Here u go: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42214

Comment: After looking at the file and trying a few things, I think you might have either missed a step in the tutorial, or the teacher missed telling you something he/she did. There are other ways to do things though. What is the result you're trying to achieve? Can you post an image? I'll continue to help you on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40742/discussion-between-anthony-forwood-and-catz).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is the preferred method for uploading blend files.

Comment: @Dontwalk really? Anthony told me to upload it there so i did, I'll make one there to then

Comment: It's all good... BSE likes to keep them all in one place I think.

Comment: @Dontwalk here u go. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1407" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1407/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do, is *remove doubles*. You have 36 doubled vertices in your model, and that is what is giving you problems it seems. After doing this, bevel gives no issues. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit* mode, then select all, and press <kbd>W</kbd>*>remove doubles*. 
Then proceed to bevel, and you shouldn't have any problems.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I was finally able to continue with it. I am really new and no almost nothing about 3d modeling so I had no idea what doubles were. Thanks to your help I was able to finally delete it.